# ArgoCD failing to sync with "SSH agent requested but SSH_AUTH_SOCK not-specified"

Tags: git, kubernetes, ssh, argocd, gitops

We have been happily using ArgoCD with public repositories for a while, but we've run into problems trying to connect ArgoCD to a private repository. We have an `Application` that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: example-app
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  destination:
    name: example-cluster
    namespace: open-cluster-management-agent
  project: ops
  source:
    path: .
    repoURL: ssh://git@github.com/example-org/example-repo.git
    targetRevision: HEAD
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true
    syncOptions:
    - Validate=false
    - ApplyOutOfSyncOnly=true
```

And a corresponding secret with the secret key that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    argocd.argoproj.io/secret-type: repository
  name: example-repo
  namespace: argocd
type: Opaque
stringData:
  sshPrivateKey: |
    -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
    ...
    -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
  url: ssh://git@github.com/example-org/example-repo.git
kind: Secret
```

ArgoCD fails to sync this app and shows the following error:

```
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error creating SSH agent: "SSH agent
requested but SSH_AUTH_SOCK not-specified"
```

I understand what that's telling me, but I'm not sure how to correct
the problem in the context of ArgoCD.

Comment: Seems to be ssh-only,  not really Git. But it's a bit weird, what's requesting the ssh agent?

Comment: I think this might be version skew; we're running argocd 2.0.x and I think the docs are for a newer version. I'm going to check version appropriate docs today and see if something has changed between the two.

Answer (score 3):

You can review possible causes from [`argoproj/argo-cd` issue 1172](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/1172)

Since you have the proper URL (`ssh://git@github.com/...`, as requested by [PR 203](https://github.com/operate-first/argocd-apps/pull/203)), double-check the indentation:

> It was an identation problem caused by me :) in the `repositories.yaml` causing a wrong unmarshalling and a empty `sshPrivateKeySecret`.
> The right version is here:
>
> ```yaml
> - sshPrivateKeySecret:
>    key: sshPrivateKey
>    name: bitbucket
>  url: git@bitbucket.org:MY-PROJECT/MY-REPO
> ```